# What are some alternatives to the Mac App Store?

Tags: software-recommendation, mac-appstore

I want something that will easily update all my applications. The Mac App Store doesn't do this with applications not purchased from the Mac App Store, I need something else. In addition, I would also like to be able to browse apps.

Comment: Alternative regarding what? Easy payment? User ratings? Featured apps? Ability to download Mac apps in general? Native app to browse applications? Integrated automatic updates? License and re-download management? Audited, signed, and sandboxed apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an app-based app store alternative, then try [Bodega](http://appbodega.com/).  It's a pretty good app that allows user to download/buy apps that existed before the app store did.  However, if that's not enough, you can always use different websites such as www.macupdate.com, www.iusethis.com etc.

Comment: I've tried Bodega, and love it, until now. Everything works in it except the browser. I can't browse apps at all, even after reinstalling it.

Comment: Hmm... it works perfectly on mine.  If Bodega isn't working, you can use AppFresh, though you can only update apps and not really browser apps.

Comment: Are you using Lion?

Comment: Yep, but there shouldn't be any difference to it as it's the same app.  Have you tried checking if the website's blocked by your firewall or your router?

Comment: How do I know what I'm looking for? I know how to check both, but I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can use apps that tests apps outgoing connection, like Little Snitch/Hands Off. I've tested it myself and it only uses the website appbodega.com, amazonaws.com and the sites where bodega gets the apps information from their respective sites.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Homebrew Cask](https://brew.sh/). Homebrew is a package manager for macOS. While originally it provided the facility to installed command line tools not provided or updated by Apple, of late it has been extended to install GUI apps.

Homebrew Cask can automate the management of apps with simple commands and you can also write Bash scripts to automate the task.

You can easily search for packages using `brew search <package_name>`. To upgrade all the installed GUI apps, you can simply run `brew cask upgrade`.